# Where does the nose.collector look for tests?

Tags: python, setuptools, nose

I want to use `nose.collector` as a test suite for setuptools, as described [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setuptools_integration.html). My package's source lives in `mypackage/src`, and I have tests in `mypackage/tests`. I have a `setup.py` that looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='1.2.3',
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
    tests_require=['nose'],
    test_suite='nose.collector',
    provides=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
)
```

However, when I run `python setup.py test`, it doesn't test anything:

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
writing src/mypackage.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/mypackage.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/mypackage.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/mypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'src/mypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

How can I tell `nose` where to look for tests? Up until now, I've been doing `nosetests -d tests`, which works fine. But I'd like to change to use `setuptools` so that I can follow the `python setup.py test` convention.

Comment: Are you working under Windows OS ?

Answer (score 1):

from the docs

> When running under setuptools, you can configure nose settings via the
>   environment variables detailed in the nosetests script usage message,
>   or the setup.cfg, ~/.noserc or ~/.nose.cfg config files.

http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setuptools_integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Fix them with `chmod -x $(find tests/ -name '*.py')`